# How do I use JavaScript's sessionstorage with JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, session

I am in the process of **spring-mvc project**. Login page is currently in progress. The problem is, I don't know how to use the `SessionStorage` function in `JSP`. I need to retrieve the data I saved in the `SessionStorage`.

I'm saving the ID value after I log in.

**Login.js**

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("Email",data.email);
```

It's where I have to use it.

**Header.jsp**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span >/****sessionStorage.getItem() ***/</span></a>
```

I've already saved and tried the session on the controller, but it didn't work.

**controller.java**

```java
session.setAttribute("id", email);
```

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span > <%session.getAttribute("id");%></span></a>
```

I need your solution. help me a lot

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using javascript so it should be in `<script>` tags. Else it will be interpreted as text. The JS sessionstorage and `HttpSession` are different things so putting something in one doesn't show it in the other and vice/versa.

Comment: @M.Deinum As you can see from my question, I am not using a script tag. I only tried using the java function Session in JSP. Since there is data stored in the session on the controller, I tried to retrieve it.

Comment: The data isn't stored in the controller, it is stored on the client side in the session storage. That is what your first code sample does/is. You are mixing concepts you aren't fully understanding and use them in a wrong way. Either use the server side `HttpSession` or use the client-side `SessionStorage` but don't expect that putting `x` into the `SessionStorage` makes it visible at the server (and vice-versa).

Comment: @M.Deinum And I just gave you a code comment to tell you where to use SessionStorage.

Comment: As stated, it is javascroipt use `<script>` tags.

Comment: @M.Deinum I know where to save a session. But I don't know how to use it.  The reason I save both the controller and the client through the session is because each has a place to use the data.  You mean, if the mix is wrong, can you bring the session value stored on the controller to session storage from the client?

Comment: example) `session.setAttribute("aa", aa);`  Client `sessionStorage.getItem("aa")` is it true??

Comment: No. As stated `HttpSession` and `SessionStorage` are different things (and you don't understand them). The `HttpSession` is **server-side state** whereas the `SessionStorage` is **client-side state**. If you put things in the `HttpSession` it isn't in the `SessionStorage` (as mentioned 2 times before) and vice-versa. If you use `session` then use `session` to retrieve it. You cannot put things in the `SessionStorage` server-side (only on the client using javascript, and this applies for the retrieval as well!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write **JavaScript** phrases using `<script />`.

First, save to an **object** in `SessionStorage`, and read the **object** you have saved.

```
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  ><i class="fa fa-user"></i> 
                    <span >
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.sessionStorage.email  = sessionStorage.getItem("Email")
                    document.write(window.sessionStorage.email)
                    </script>
                    </span>
                    </a>
```